# Calculating $g^{(1000)}(0)$ of $g(x)=\exp(x^{999})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

$g^{(1000)}(0)$ of $$g(x)=\exp(x^{999})$$

I know that we can write $$g(x)=\exp(x^{999}) = \sum_{n=0} \frac{x^{999n}}{n!}$$

So I looks like it should be $0$ but what's the reasoning behind it?

Comment: What happens when you take the derivative of the series 1000 times?

Comment: Nope, it shouldn't. You've forgotten the free term.

Comment: @KolyaIvankov what do you mean?

Comment: Remember, the product rule'll create an extra non-$x$ term.

Comment: Try calculating $g^{(k)}(0)$ of the same series, for $k=1,2,3$ to see what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: first compute $g'(x)$.  You get a product of two terms.  Now take $g''(x)$ using the product and chain rules.  You should get something that looks like $p(x)\exp(x^{999})$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial.  You should be able to imagine what will happen with $998$ more derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is also fine:
$$g(x)=e^{x^{999}}=1+x^{999}+\frac{x^{1998}}{2}+\frac{x^{2997}}{6}+\cdots.$$
$$g^{(1000)}(x)=\frac{1998\cdots 999 x^{998}}{2}+\frac{2997\cdots 1998x^{1997}}{6}+\cdots.$$
$$g^{(1000)}(0)=0.$$